# How can I fool a site into believing that I'm using IE when I'm really on Firefox or Safari for MAC

Tags: asp.net, mac, firefox

I use a mac. I do have vm ware fusion so i can access the site though IE. my problem is i dont like to use the fusion unless total necessary. It uses a lot of memory and battery, plus when im mobile though wifi card the internet connection can be spotty.

On this website I can access most of the pages but when I try to get into one of the modules it never works it tells me only IE is supported.

I would like to either find an emulator for IE that I can run or find a way to change my firefox settings so that I dont get the error any more. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

Will do this, but firefox will still format the page as firefox so will look different if it functions at all.   This tricks the web page into thinking you are using IE but the developer has most likely used some formatting options that are unique to IE.

good luck

Answer (score 2):

For Safari

Enable developer menu:

Preferences > Advanced > Show Developer menu in menunar

Then go to the Develop menu > User Agent > Internet Explorer 8.0